# Push-forward of vector fields of Heisenberg type group $\mathbb R \times \mathbb C$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I am learning some geometry by myself, so pleas be explicit as possible. My aim is to calculate the structure constants of the Lie algebra of $\mathbb R \times \mathbb C$ equipped with the low 
$$(x_0,x) \cdot (y_0,y) = (x_0+y_0+\frac{1}{2}Im(x\bar{y}), x+y)$$
I think that, with the trivial chart $(\mathbb R \times \mathbb C,Id_{\mathbb R \times \mathbb C}) $ this can be viewed as a real manifold. Moreover, it is a lie group.

Let $\ell_{(z_0,z)}$ be the left multiplication operator by $(z_0,z) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb C$

I am confused with the combination of the real and complex variables in the definition of the group, for a basis of the tangent vectors at (0,0) I guess we should take something like $$\partial_{x_0}|_{(0,0)} , \partial_{x}|_{(0,0)} , \partial_{\bar{x}}|_{(0,0)}$$
but when I try to push-forward one of them by $\ell_{(z_0,z)}$ using the Jacobian matrix technique, which turns to be a $2\times 3$ matrix, I loose information about the last vector field (with the bar). I know I am probably doing a stupid error. I don't have time now to include my explicit computation, but I will add them later if it is needed.

---

**Update :** 
I want to add that I am interested in results without using matrix representation, for learning purpose and for my intention of doing computations in higher dimension and in other similar lie groups.

I tried to imitate the computation done in the following lecture note by M.L. Fels : [An Introduction to Differential Geometry through Computation](http://www.math.usu.edu/~fels/complete.pdf) Page 61 § 4.2

$$ {\ell_{(z_0,z)}}_* \partial_{x_0}|_{(0,0)} = J|_{(0,0)} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ 
$$ {\ell_{(z_0,z)}}_* \partial_{x}|_{(0,0)} = J|_{(0,0)} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ 
$$ {\ell_{(z_0,z)}}_* \partial_{\bar x}|_{(0,0)} = J|_{(0,0)} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$ 
where J|_{(0,0)}, is the Jacobian matrix ${\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -\frac{1}{4}\bar{z} & \frac{1}{4} z \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}_{|(0,0)} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -\frac{1}{4}\bar{z} & \frac{1}{4} z \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ associated to the application $\ell_{(z_0,z)}$.

I am confusing the actual tangent vector at $\ell_{(z_0,z)}(0,0) = (z_0,z)$ with its coefficient in the base $\partial_{x_0}|_{(z_0,z)} , \partial_{x}|_{(z_0,z)} , \partial_{\bar{x}}|_{(z_0,z)}$.

The problem is that  these computations work well in  open sets of $\mathbb R^n$ but are not consistent when $\mathbb C$ is introduced. I guess I have to proceed otherwise? Probably by  rethinking about the chart and try to devise $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ ?

To illustrate the problem : if we do the computation for the following

$${\ell_{(z_0,z)}}_* \partial_{x}|_{(0,0)} =  \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{4} \bar{z} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

the result is only two coefficients, but we need three to write the tangent vector in $\{\partial_{x_0}|_{(z_0,z)} , \partial_{x}|_{(z_0,z)} , \partial_{\bar{x}}|_{(z_0,z)}\}$

Comment: You should probably show us how you found that 2 by 3 matrix, because it sounds like something went wrong there.

Comment: @Danu Thank you. Pleas  read my update.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "push **forward**".

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff♦ Thanks, I hadn't noticed. I have French background.

Answer (score 2):

Let an element of the Heisenberg group be
 $$g=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a & b\\
0 & 1 & c\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).$$
Then you have
$$ L_{g}\left(X\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a & b\\
0 & 1 & c\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x & y\\
0 & 1 & z\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x+a & y+az+b\\
0 & 1 & z+c\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right),$$
Writing this in another way you have that $$L_{\left(a,b,c\right)}\left(x,y,z\right)=\left(x+a,\,y+az+b,\,z+c\right).$$
Now take the differential and you have the push forward
$$L_{g*}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & a\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).$$
For example let's take the vectors
$$\left(E_{1}\right)_{\mathbb{1}}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right),\,\,\left(E_{2}\right)_{\mathbb{1}}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right),\,\,\left(E_{3}\right)_{\mathbb{1}}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right),$$
Then for every point $g$ in the Heisenberg group you have a tangent base given by $$\left(E_{i}\right)_{g}=L_{g*}\left(E_{1}\right)_{\mathbb{1}},$$
  i.e.$$\left(E_{1}\right)_{g}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right),\,\,\left(E_{2}\right)_{g}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & a\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right),\,\,\left(E_{3}\right)_{g}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & a\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you, but honestly I didn't understand where is my complex variable, all my question is about that variable, and I want to stick to the abstract definition of the group without using matrix representation if it is possible. Secondly : can you explain to me pleas when you  have said "Now take the differential and you have the push forward ". Thanks again.

Comment: If you want that we correct your calculation maybe you should include them explicitly, otherwise I just assumed you wanted to find the pushforward (not "push foreword") of the Heisenberg Group. By the way, what is the abstract definition of the Heisenberg Group? The one you gave at the beginning?

Comment: I included more details in my update. thank you.